# How do I replace HTML escapes in an input stream before parsing it to XML?

Tags: java, android

I have an input stream which is being converted to XML, and read.  When I get down to some text elements in the XML, they are truncated. I believe the parser is dropping everything after escaped HTML such as &  Here is the code getting the input stream and then getting the text element.

```
String hvurl = "https://www.mysite.com/api/a/" + answerId;
in = OpenHttpConnection(hvurl); 

Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db;

try {
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = db.parse(in);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}     

...
//Now when I get the text element, it's truncated
//---get the <varietalTitle> elements under the <varietal> 
// element---
NodeList varietalTitleNodes = 
    (varietalElement).getElementsByTagName("varietaltitle");

//---convert a Node into an Element---
Element varietalTitleElement = (Element) varietalTitleNodes.item(0);

//---get all the child nodes under the <varietaltitle> element---
NodeList varietalTitleTextNodes = 
    ((Node) varietalTitleElement).getChildNodes();

//---retrieve the text of the <varietalid> element---
strVarietalTitle = ((Node) varietalTitleTextNodes.item(0)).getNodeValue();
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of an "HTML escape" that the XML compiler gets wrong?

Comment: <varietaldesc>(ZIHN-fuhn-dehl): A spicy red wine with blueberry &amp; blackberry is a match.</varietaldesc>

Comment: When I get the node value into the string, strVarietalTitle = (ZIHN-fuhn-dehl): A spicy red wine with blueberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cant get where the problem occurs. My guess use the `normalize()` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#normalize()) as below.

Try this:

```
 strVarietalTitle = ((Node) varietalTitleTextNodes.item(0)).getNodeValue().normalize();
```

From documentation Normalize():

*Puts Puts all Text nodes in the full depth of the sub-tree underneath this Node, including attribute nodes, into a "normal" form where only structure (e.g., elements, comments, processing instructions, CDATA sections, and entity references) separates Text nodes, i.e., there are neither adjacent Text nodes nor empty Text nodes. This can be used to ensure that the DOM view of a document is the same as if it were saved and re-loaded, and is useful when operations (such as XPointer [XPointer] lookups) that depend on a particular document tree structure are to be used. If the parameter "normalize-characters" of the DOMConfiguration object attached to the Node.ownerDocument is true, this method will also fully normalize the characters of the Text nodes.
    Note: In cases where the document contains CDATASections, the normalize operation alone may not be sufficient, since XPointers do not differentiate between Text nodes and CDATASection nodes.*

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem occurs either.  Between parsing the inputstream to XML and then getting the node value into the string.  <varietaldesc>(ZIHN-fuhn-dehl): A spicy red wine with blueberry &amp; blackberry is a match.</varietaldesc>
is the actual XML that I can see in a browser, but when I get the final string variable, all I get is (ZIHN-fuhn-dehl): A spicy red wine with blueberry

Comment: Thanks, normalized fixed the problem.              try {
                db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = db.parse(in);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Comment: @Poolczar @DroidBase Many many many thanx to Poolczar and DroidBase for saving my valuable time, i was also facing such issue with &apos; . normalize() has solved this issue.

Comment: upvoted +1 , i cant give you more otherwise i will upvote many. Thanx DroidBase once again.

Answer (score 0):

An XML parser should cope with character entities such as "&" ... assuming that's what you are talking about.

One possibility is that your input contains particular named entities that the XML parser doesn't know about.